# Wireless network interface ra0 does not start at boot

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, upstart, network-interface

I recently installed USB Wireless Adapter based on **Ralink RT5370** chip on my Ubuntu 10.04.
Manufacturer drivers are installed properly and now I have ra0 wireless interface configured in /etc/network/interfaces like so:

```
auto ra0
iface ra0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.25
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
    dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1
    wpa-ssid <my-wpa-psk>
    wpa-psk <my-wpa-psk>
```

Everything works OK when I bring it up with "**ifup -a**" or "**ifup ra0**" - I can ping, surf Internet. Networking is active.

But I can not figure it out why it is not brought up on boot?
All other ifaces such as **eth0** and **lo** are loaded OK.

I tried to create some executable scripts in **/etc/init.d** with **ifup ra0** command inside and updating them via **update-rc.d**, but soon I realized that none of placed there is executed during boot (simply added mkdir inside one of them and nothing changed)
It worth to mention that there is **Upstart** on my system.

But I want it to behave like it should understanding **auto ra0**